# REGEX L(r) = {a^n b^m : n + m is even}, r =?

Tags: regex, math, automata, formal-languages, computability

So I did a problem earlier that said:

```
L(r) = {w in {a,b}* : w contains at least 2 a's}
```

For that one I said `{a^2n , b}` because that guarantees a string like `aab` or `aabaab` etc. Not sure how to approach the one I posted about in the title. Possibly a solution might be `a^2n, b^2m` so its always even, but also 2 odd numbers like `a^n b^3m` is also always even. Am i allowed to set boundaries like `n>=m`?

Thank you!

Comment: Consider the automaton which accepts  `a^n` when n is even. The "failure" case would be that `n` is odd. In that "failure" case, you want a following automaton `b^m` which accepts when `m` is odd. Otherwise, you want a following automaton `b^m` which accepts when `m` is even.

Comment: what about `^(?=(?:..)*$)[ab]*$` (https://regex101.com/r/1aldWm/1)

Comment: @Corion how would I write that in terms of r? I understand the logic just not the syntax.

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul I don't understand that program and what the symbols mean, we use different stuff in my class.

Comment: I think this question better suits [Mathematics StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com) site and it's `regular-expressions` tag. Also, are you sure there is a possibility to use a regular expression for this? Seems more like a grammar is to be used here, since irregularities you mention oppose the "regular" part in "regex" :)

Comment: @Asunez As I showed, the language is regular, as it can be accepted by a DFA.

Comment: @solnay - I would assume that the notation is covered in your course material? Most likely you have some fancy notation involving circles pointing to other circles or stuff like that. See the recommendation for a different Stack Exchange site.

Comment: `^(?=(?:..)*$)` is a lookahead which allows to check the length is even (any times a sequence of two character `..`) without moving forward input cursor, anchored at the beginning of input, `^[ab]*$` ensures the string contains only `a` or `b`

Answer (score 3):

You correctly observe that `n` and `m` must either be both even or both odd. It only needs to be added that an odd number is one more than an even number.

A simple regular expression for "an even number of `a`s" ( `{a2n : n ≥ 0}`) is `(aa)*`, while "an odd number of `a`s" is `(aa)*a`.

Building on that, we can two cases for the original question: `(aa)*(bb)*` and `(aa)*a(bb)*b`, which can be combined into `(aa)*(ab+ε)(bb)*`. (Assuming you are using `+` for alternation and ε for the empty string.)

Answer (score 0):

r=((a+b)^2)*  ,i think this regular expression is also giving the right answer

Comment: From Review: Could you please explain what the RegEx does?